# How do I get Ajax form submissions to work in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, form-submit

I'm very new to the AJAX and Javascript world and I'm trying to implement [Scott Hanselman's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCPreview4UsingAjaxAndAjaxForm.aspx) example of form submission to update part of a page. I have copied his example almost word-for-word and I can't seem to get it to work. When I click the submit button the controller action is called successfully but the result is rendered in the browser as a new page, instead of updating just the span that I specified in the Ajax form.

Here is my view code:

```
<asp:Content ID="indexHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("TestAction", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "target" }))
       { %>

        <%= Html.TextBox("TextBox")%>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <span id="target" />

    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

And my controller action:

```
    public string TestAction(string TextBox)
    {
        return TextBox;
    }
```

And I have included the following lines in the master page

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js"type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But all it seems to do is call the action and render the result as a new page, instead of updating the target span. Here are some small screenshots to illustrate what's happening.

[Screenshot 1 http://martindoms.com/scr1.JPG](http://martindoms.com/scr1.JPG)

[Screenshot 2 http://martindoms.com/scr2.JPG](http://martindoms.com/scr2.JPG)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the javascript include in your master page in the wrong order.
Reorder so that MicrosoftAjax.js is included first of the three and it will work.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing some ideas out there...

http://www.asp.net/learn/MVC/tutorial-33-cs.aspx

Your controller action is in a class defined like so?

```
public class MyController : Controller
```

Apparently the name of the class has to end with the word controller.

Comment: I'm using the default HomeController so yes, it is called HomeController and extends Controller.